# JQuery: Hide children, show nth child?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

This is really weird and should be simple.

I have an array of images within a tags within a div, eg:

```
<div id="images">
<a href="#"><img src="img1.jpg"/></a>
<a href="#"><img src="img2.jpg"/></a>
<a href="#"><img src="img3.jpg"/></a>
</div>
```

I want to hide all of them, but loop through and show the nth one, so I created this image slider style script:

```
var atags = $('#images').children().length;

$('#images').children().hide();

$('#images a:first').show();

var i=0

while (i <= atags){

$('#images').children().delay(4000).hide();

$("images:nth-child(" + i + ")").show();

i = i + 1;
}
```

The issue is that no other a tags, despite the first out side the loop, get displayed. They all remain hidden dispite the .show(). It appears the line `$("images:nth-child(" + i + ")").show();` just doesnt work.

Can anyone point me in the right direction with this?

Comment: @GeorgeCummins oops sorry forget to paste it in. Its is the number of A Tags within the parent element. Amended above

Comment: What's the `delay()` good for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`images != #images` plus you need to select the actual images not the container:

```
$("#images img:nth-child(" + i + ")").show();
```

But I would just use `eq`, not sure if the above will work given that the images are *inside* a tag:

```
$("#images img").eq(i).show();
```

In any case, you don't need that `while` loop, just use jQuery's `each` to loop the collection.

Also note that `delay` only works if there's an animation queue and this not your case.

Comment: Or just use the `$('#images').children()` which are already selected in the previous statement…

Comment: @Bergi: The code in the question though is a bit of a mess. I tried explaining the error, but OP should probably loop with `each`, don't know why the `while` loop...